# How to delete all ?source line code in URL with rewrite rule for the 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Please help me to write the correct `RewriteRule` for the 301 redirect (`.htaccess` under subdomain `blog.example.com`) for the links like:

from

```
https://blog.example.com/?source=tag_archive---------0-----------
```

redirect to

```
https://example.com/blog/
```

---

I use these lines in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^blog\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^source=tag_archive---------0-----------(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/  [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

With the example above I got

```
https://example.com/blog/?source=tag_archive---------0-----------
```

but need

```
https://example.com/blog/
```

(without part `?source=tag_archive---------0-----------`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Apache 2.4+ you need to add the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag to the `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://domainname.com/blog/  [QSD,R=301,L]
```

(Alternatively, if you are still on Apache 2.2, then append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string - effectively an empty query string. The `?` itself will not be in the redirect response.)

`^(.*)$` (the `RewriteRule` *pattern*) - since you are matching *any* URL-path and not using the backreference, this can be simplified to `^`.

The `NC` and `NE` flags are not required here.

However, as noted above, this redirects any URL-path. If you specifically want to redirect `https://blog.example.com/?source=tag...` *only* then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to `^$` (an empty URL-path). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://domainname.com/blog/  [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you MrWhite for your detailed description, 
it works well for me now with QSD